# RabbitMQ- do I need to 'start' the consumer/receiver script on the first message?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm currently learning about RabbitMQ, using the PHP tutorials on their website. In all of their examples they initiate both the `new_task.php` and the `receiver.php` scripts upon sending the first message.

In production, how would I ensure `receiver.php` is running, and able to accept new messages?

Comment: I don't understand what is the question. How can you be sure that (any kind of) process is running?